# evaluate expression before it is put in lambda

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I have the following piece of code in my `.emacs`:

```
(dolist (mode '(scheme emacs-lisp lisp clojure))
  (add-hook
   (intern (concat (symbol-name mode) "-mode-hook"))
   (lambda ()
     (progn
        (run-programming-hook)
        (message "%s" (concat (symbol-name mode) "-mode")))
```

Obviously the `mode` variable is void when lambda gets to execute.  The question is how I evaluate `mode` in such a way that it doesn't get into a lambda as a variable but rather as a value in that variable?  In other words, I want the message to be printed when the hook is run.

Comment: Just a quick note: your "obviously ... is void" is wrong -- it *should* *not* be this way, and Emacs Lisp is one of very few languages where this still happens.  It's called dynamic scope.  Related to this, look for the `lexical-let` form in Emacs, which is a hack that emulates the saner behavior that would work.

Answer (score 11):

What you can use is [backquote](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html):

```
(dolist (mode '(scheme emacs-lisp lisp clojure))
  (add-hook
   (intern (concat (symbol-name mode) "-mode-hook"))
   `(lambda ()
       (run-programming-hook)
       (message "%s" ,(concat (symbol-name mode) "-mode")))))
```